# Find peaks/thresholds from data/plot using Python

Tags: python, graph, plot, cluster-analysis

I have the following plot from some data using Python:

[image]

The example data could be something like this:

```
339
305
276
248
263
424
451
438
410
399
399
398
.
.
.
```

What I'm trying to do is get the indexes of all the peaks. Please note that I just want the maximum peaks. What I'm currently doing is smoothing the data using Gaussian smoothing to remove the semi peaks and troughs to get smooth curves and finding the indexes of the maxima of those. It works, but it's not a very clean solution.

I was wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this using some clustering method such as kmeans? Could someone point me towards a solution?

Comment: Why is that not a clean solution? What does the data you posted represent? I presume it is y-values but not clear.

Comment: It's a periodic signal. If you can safely assume that this periodicity is maintained, you can look for the maximum value within certain time windows.

Comment: The data is the interbeat interval of the heart, so yes, in a sense, it is the y value. As for periodicity, yes, the data would be periodic, but it may vary and hence I can't just choose a window.

As for why it's not overly clean, I'm altering the data I'm getting back. I'd much prefer it if I could work with the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, using Gaussian smoothing probably means you are doing what is called **kernel density estimation**.

This is - in particular for low-dimensional data - to be considered good statistical practise. You may want to read up on KDE to find out how to choose the kernel bandwidth, but other than that, stick to this established method.

k-means is only beneficial when you have multiple variables, as it optimizes all of them at once. But you would have to choose k, which you probably don't know beforehand.

Try to approach it from a *density estimation* point of view, don't try to do something too fancy.

Comment: Thanks, KDE looks to be the way to go. Simplest is the best way, it seems.